# How can fetch city from json php url dynamically in android and display on navigation drawer

Tags: android, json

Here is to display a news from below `json` data. in navigation menu but not fetched. 
in that `menuitem`

```
[{"news_cat_id":"118DFDD8_7E4B_FCE6_CFF3_48CCF0269680","cat_name":"Desh","cat_code":"Desh","cat_url":"Desh","cat_title":"Desh","cat_keyword":"Desh","cat_desc":"Desh","cat_dependency":"0","galli_display":"0","highlight":"0","cat_position":"1","cat_subposition":"0","status":"0","Time":"2016-03-03 06:44:42"},{"news_cat_id":"2A129D1A_DD90_09A6_B585_51189B2C3DB9","cat_name":"Mumbai","cat_code":"Mumbai","cat_url":"Mumbai","cat_title":"Mumbai","cat_keyword":"Mumbai","cat_desc":"Mumbai","cat_dependency":"0","galli_display":"0","highlight":"0","cat_position":"2","cat_subposition":"0","status":"0","Time":"2016-03-03 06:45:14"}
```

here is an fetch city name frpm json data but app was crashed..

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    ArrayList<List_items> list_items_arr = new ArrayList<List_items>();


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }


    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String > {
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            String url = "http://elitesolution.co.in/galli/menu.php";
            ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
            String jsonstr = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.POST);
            Log.d("Response:", ">" + jsonstr);


                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
                   JSONArray contacts = jsonObject.getJSONArray(jsonstr);
                   // JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonstr);
                    for(int i=0;i<contacts.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject c=contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String city=c.getString("cat_url");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            return jsonstr;
        }
    }  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int list_items = item.getItemId();


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing your json response like this:

```
JsonArray jsonArray=new JsonArray("Your json string");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
JsonObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
String city=jsonObject.getString("cat_url");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create arraylist to store yout data

```
ArrayList<List_items> list_items_arr = new ArrayList<List_items>();
```

Create class for Lisr_items

```
      public class List_items{
       String item_id,item_name;
    public void setItem_id(String item_id) {
            this.item_id = item_id;
        }

   public void setItem_name(String item_name) {
        this.item_name = item_name;
      }
  }
```

get the response from server and parse it

```
JsonArray jsonArray=new JsonArray("Your Json Responce");
      for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++){
             JSONObject list_obj=items.getJSONObject(i);
                List_items list_items = new List_items();
                list_items.setItem_name(list_obj.getString("cat_url"));
               list_items.setItem_id(list_obj.getString("news_cat_id"));
         list_items_arr .add(list_items);
     }
```

Comment: but how can display it on navigation menu items

Comment: pass this arraylist to navigationadapter

Comment: follow this tutorial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) and then pass arraylist to navigationadapter

Comment: how can add menu and submenu into navigation drawer

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
JsonArray jsonArray=new JsonArray("Your json responce");
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
  JsonObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJsonObject(i);
  String city=jsonObject.getString("cat_url");
  Toast.makeText(this, ""+city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```